# Are web publishing tools available for VS2017 in MSBuild directory?

Tags: .net, msbuild

I have the web developer tools installed on my VS2017 IDE and the Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll is found in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\
```

This is fine when running my build inside VS2017.

However, when I run my build from the command line, MSBuild searches for the web.publishing tasks in the following location:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll
```

And in this location it is missing.  For Visual Studio 2015 I don't remember installing anything special to make this work and for v14.0, the dll is in both locations.  Does anyone know what I am missing?